# MySql 'LIKE' query performing slowly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, indexing

I have two tables in my local server database. which one has **"10k"** rows with keywords column .
In another Tables have **850k** rows with strings. my task was fetching a string which matched with  **"keywords"**

```
$res_count = 1000;
$keyword_sql = "SELECT tbid,keywords FROM `tbl_keywords1` LIMIT 0,$res_count";
$keyword_result = mysqli_query($conn, $keyword_sql);
while ($keyword_row = $keyword_result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $keyword_res[]  = $keyword_row;   
    $key_wrd        = $keyword_row['keywords'];    
    $sql            = "SELECT country,state,city,COUNT(tbid) AS cnt FROM `tbl_keywords` 
                              WHERE MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ('$key_wrd' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                              GROUP BY country,state";    
    $result         = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $res[] = $row;
    }    
}
```

My Problem was it's taking too much time.
Is there any method for getting result quickly

Comment: You are using sql query inside a loop so if the outer loop count is 1000, then 1000 mysql query will be executed and will cause delay as mysql query is time expensive. Try yo get data within single sql query using `join` or `unions`

Comment: I took the liberty of changing your subject to reflect your actual question: `Q: Is there any method for getting result quickly?`  A: yes.  Two things: 1) Try to refashion your query into *ONE* select (instead of a loop of different selects!)  2) If its still too slow, then refine your WHERE clause to be more selective. Ideally, selective on one or more columns that you've indexed.

Comment: you have an n+1 query thats why its slow, just like the others have said, you could change your query into just one whole select, and do you really need to output a thousand keywords at a time? im sure that won't even fit the screen if you're in mobile

Comment: @Ajith  I need to get all string which is matched with keywords so I am using 1000 keywords. I have no idea how can I **1) Try to refashion your query into ONE select (instead of a loop of different selects!)**. please help with the example code.

Comment: @kavin my task was to export a CSV with a matched string. while I am fetching Its takes time.

Comment: @Nishanthan I have added an answer now please check and let me know

Comment: Which `city` do you expect?  That is, is it an invalid `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with my below sql query

```
$res_count = 1000;
$keyword_sql = "SELECT tbid,keywords FROM `tbl_keywords1` LIMIT 0,$res_count";
$keyword_result = mysqli_query($conn, $keyword_sql);

$likeOr = array();
while ($keyword_row = $keyword_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $key_wrd        = $keyword_row['keywords'];    
    $likeOr[]       = "keywords LIKE '%".$key_wrd."%' ";
}


if(count($likeOr) > 0 ){

    $sql            = "SELECT country,state,city,COUNT(tbid) AS cnt FROM `tbl_keywords` 
                          WHERE ".implode("OR", $likeOr)."
                          GROUP BY country,state";    
    $result         = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);    

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $res[] = $row;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nope Bro.Your coding using **OR**.So I cant get all data. in my old query getting  219 records for a single keyword. But In our new query getting totally of 21 records.

Comment: if I am searching with the keyword "biomedical".query will search the whole table .and return a **219** result. my task was to search with 10k keywords like this. and with a quick response.

Comment: Can you debug and see this `SELECT country,state,city,COUNT(tbid) AS cnt FROM tbl_keywords  WHERE keywords LIKE '%biomedical%' GROUP BY country,state`

Comment: My above answer is the way to avoid looping sql query, but to identify the real issue I need to get the real data of your database. But Still I can help if you provide the debug results

Comment: But it is 850K * 1000 `LIKEs` with a leading wild card.